# Declaring an array in CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to Declare $GroupName array and add a couple statements for the array. I have an additional code from a different script and am trying to create an array for that script. I am trying to test the Row.Category = group and the Row.excluded = false. Then it will check the $groupname Array for duplicates. If no duplicates are found, populate $groupname.

I am need help just creating the array since I am a powershell novice.

```
  $GroupName = @(column1 = "Domain")(column2 = "Account")
If ($_.category0 -eq "Group") -and ($_.Excluded -match "False")
 "Account0", "Domain0" | sort Account0 -Unique
```

How do I improve the following code above to display the 2 columns in the new CSV.

Comment: An existing csv file, or a new file from scratch?

Comment: I would recommend having a read up on [arrays and hash tables](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/powershell-basics-arrays-hash-tables)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I am going to use an existing csv file and powershell code and create an Array called $Groupname and add a few if statements to it then export port it to a new file

Answer (score 1):

This is one method to achieve what you're after, creating a **new** CSV file:

```
$Object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{ Domain=''; Account='' }
$Object | Export-CSV $env:temp\MyCSV.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

We create a new PSObject called `$Object` and provide a `hashtable` object with the structure you require to the `-Property` parameter.

We then pass the PSObject down the pipeline to the `Export-CSV` cmdlet. Adding `-NoTypeInformation` on the end allows us to create a clean CSV file without additional information from PowerShell that other systems would not recognise.

However, I should note there are other ways to create/generate CSVs, especially if you're wanting to populate them with data.

Comment: What about a different method

Comment: @Sprengdilly What is wrong with this method? It would create a CSV with two columns? You need to create your objects with properties which is what export-csv wants